# Flutter FCM localized notification parameter are not receive

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using title_loc_key parameter to show localized notification.Tested it when app is background work fine.But when app is foreground i must handle it manually.

So I trying to handle it in onMessage callback but i only got data like `onMessage: {notification: {title: null, body: null}, data: {...}}` the title and body always null which is normal cause i am not send those parameter form server.But title_loc_key parameter is disappear.

Does it supposed to receive data like `onMessage: {notification: {title_loc_key:key , title_loc_args: [arg1,arg2]}, data: {...}}` isn't it ? if not or this is plugin bug anyone have better idea to fix it? only way i can think is also put title_loc_key parameter in data payload.

Comment: I having that same issue unable to handle notification when app is in foreground.

Comment: @ParthBhanderi If you are only using title and body parameter it should work.

Comment: this is my payload:
const payload = {
        notification: {
        title: 'test notification',
        body: 'test notification',
        sound: 'default',
           }
        }

Comment: I tested on ios.Keys are little different but all parameter are included.Do you used to dev fcm on Android ? I don't know is this just how normal fcm work difference between ios and android or it's is flutter plugin bug.

Comment: yes, in android and ios notification behaviour are different in ios it's working perfect but in android notification are not shutter down in notification trey. don't know it's flutter plugin issue or anything else.